# c++ link temporary allocations in function to custom allocator?

Tags: c++, memory, allocator

I am currently working on some simple custom allocators in c++ which generally works allready. I also overloaded the new/delete operators to allocate memory from my own allocator. Anyways I came across some scenarios where I don't really know where the memory comes from like this:

```
    void myFunc(){
          myObj testObj();
          ....do something with it
    }
```

In this case testObj would only be valid inside the function, but where would its memory come from? Is there anyway I could link it to my allocator? Would I have to create to object using new and delete or is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(`myObj testObj();` declares a function named `testObj` which returns a `myObj`. Use `myObj testObj;` instead.)

The memory comes from the stack. It will be `auto`-matically destroyed when leaving the scope.

---

To use your `new` and `delete` you must of course call `new` and `delete`:

```
myObj* p_testObj = new myObj;
...
delete p_testObj;
```

But allocation on stack is the most efficient since it just involves 1 instruction `sub esp, ??`. I don't see a reason to use custom allocation unless `myObj` is huge.

Comment: Isn't having those parenthesis after testObj just as valid?

Comment: I am just asking because I want to allocate all my memory in one place.- I propably will use new/delete then. and what I wrote is not a function but a simple call to the constructor :)

Comment: @Matti: yes, but not what you want: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2

Comment: as far as I know its just a call to the constructor? or would it need arguments?

Comment: @user: `myObj testObj;` reserves memory on the stack, then call the default constructor.

Comment: well I am just confused since you can also call an objects constructor like this std::string  _str("I am A String");

Comment: @user: That's because you have 1 argument to pass, and a function prototype would look have a type e.g. `std::string f(std::string)`, so there's no way the constructor syntax be confused as function declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked it myselft, and now that I think about it, it makes sense!